# jQuery: FadeOut then SlideUp

Tags: jquery, fadeout, slideup

If an item is being deleted then I would like to fade it out and slide the other elements up to fill the empty space. Now, when I use `fadeOut()` the item doesn't have a height at the end which results in the other items jumping up (instead of sliding up nicely).

How can I `slideUp()` and element right after `fadeOut()`?

Comment: I rewrote mine so it's a toggle now.

Comment: It should be noted that the reason fadeOut causes a jump is that after the opacity is animated to 0, the display is set to none. fadeTo doesn't do this which is why the below solutions work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
jQuery.fn.fadeThenSlideToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
  if (this.is(":hidden")) {
    return this.slideDown(speed, easing).fadeTo(speed, 1, easing, callback);
  } else {
    return this.fadeTo(speed, 0, easing).slideUp(speed, easing, callback);
  }
};
```

I tested it on JQuery 1.3.2, and it does work.

Edit: This is the code I called it from.  #slide-then-fade is the ID of a button element, article-text is a class on a div tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slide-then-fade').click(function() {
    $('.article-text').fadeThenSlideToggle();
  });
});
```

Edit 2: Modified to use the built-in slideUp.

Edit 3: Rewritten as a toggle, and using fadeTo

Comment: I had to drop the 'easing' parameter in order to get the 'callback' to work.

Comment: Ah, OK. As I recall, the slides and fades have different arguments for easing, so the easing argument was useless anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to make this nested? I tried this > http://jsfiddle.net/59CQf/2/ but it doesn't work

Answer (score 54):

Sounds like it would be better to use the jQuery [fadeTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeTo) command

```
 $(function() {

     $("#myButton").click(function() {
         $("#myDiv").fadeTo("slow", 0.00, function(){ //fade
             $(this).slideUp("slow", function() { //slide up
                 $(this).remove(); //then remove from the DOM
             });
         });

     });

});
```

[Working Demo here](http://jsbin.com/avebe/16).

By performing each command in the callback function of the preceding command, the command will not run until the previous one completes; a "jump" occurs when the element is removed from the DOM without waiting for the slideUp to complete.

Comment: nice demo, wish more folks would do it.

Comment: Wish stackoverflow would provide a sandbox

Comment: Thanks. I discovered jsbin here on stackoverflow and have been using it since to provide workable demos in answers - http://jsbin.com

Comment: seems unnecessary to use 0.01. this works fine with 0 without changing your version of jQuery (at least in Chrome) http://jsbin.com/avebe/16/edit

Comment: @Simon - and in Firefox 3.6.13 and in IE8 too. It does seem uneccessary, will update answer.

Comment: @Simon - yes, that does seem to be the case (I think I must have made the assumption that `fadeTo` also ended in hiding the element, hence the original 0.01 value for opacity - learn something new everyday!)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you chain it?

```
$('myelement').fadeOut().slideUp();
```

**EDIT**:

Maybe [this](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/02/simple-effects-plugins) will help instead?

Comment: No it fades to nothing and then does a hard move on the DOM element.

Comment: No, it jumps up at the end of the fadeOut().

Comment: Your link shows how to fadeOut and SlideUp at the same time. I would slideUp after fadeOut has ended.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#id").fadeIn(500, function () {

    $("#id2").slideUp(500).delay(800).fadeOut(400);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('.row').animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'slow').slideUp();`

[demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/a1fdu3qp/)

Answer (score -1):

The fadeOut function takes a second optional argument of a callback function, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
$('elementAbove').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('elementBelow').slideUp();
});
```

EDIT: forgot to add the speed of the fadeOut as the first parameter

Comment: it doesn't work because you esentially did the same thing as chaining.  you need to fade to 1% first and then roll up

Comment: I'd disagree that this is the same thing as chaining: with chaining you could end up with both animations firing simultaneously due to the way timeouts; using a callback for the slideUp() should in theory ensure that it fires only after fadeOut has finished executing.

Comment: @Nick Berardi: I see what you mean about fading to 1% - I've just tried a quick demo and using fadeTo(speed, 0.1, callback) seems to do the trick.