# fadeOut() and slideUp() at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I have found [jQuery: FadeOut then SlideUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734554/jquery-fadeout-then-slideup) and it's good, but it's not the one.

How can I `fadeOut()` and `slideUp()` at the same time? I tried two separate `setTimeout()` calls with the same delay but the `slideUp()` happened as soon as the page loaded.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can do something like this, this is a full toggle version:

```
$("#mySelector").animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'slow');
```

For strictly a fadeout:

```
$("#mySelector").animate({ height: 0, opacity: 0 }, 'slow');
```

Comment: @Powerlord - Woops you're right, was testing the showing here, doh

Answer (score 25):

Directly animating height results in a jerky motion on some web pages.  However, combining a CSS transition with jQuery's `slideUp()` makes for a smooth disappearing act.

```js
const slideFade = (elem) => {
   const fade = { opacity: 0, transition: 'opacity 400ms' };
   elem.css(fade).slideUp();
   };

slideFade($('#mySelector'));
```

Fiddle with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/00Lodcqf/435

[image: bye]

In some situations, a very quick 100 millisecond pause to allow more fading creates a slightly smoother experience:

```js
   elem.css(fade).delay(100).slideUp();
```

This is the solution I used in the dna-engine project where you can view the code ([github.com/dna-engine/dna-engine](https://github.com/dna-engine/dna-engine)) for the `dna.ui.slideFade()` function to see additional support for toggling and callbacks.

Comment: Thanks. Nick Craver's accepted answer did not work for me for the reason mentioned in CodeKoalas's answer. However, I prefer your code because it lets you set different timings for the fade and opacity effects. (E.g., I like the look when you set fade a little faster than the slideup.) However, I'm not sure about your smoothness claim. On my computer, the effect produced by your code is smooth in IE but not particularly so in Chrome.

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer by "Nick Craver" is definitely the way to go.  The only thing I'd add is that his answer doesn't actually "hide" it, meaning the DOM still sees it as a viable element to display.

This can be a problem if you have margin's or padding's on the 'slid' element... they will still show.  So I just added a callback to the animate() function to actually hide it after animation is complete:

```
$("#mySelector").animate({ 
   height: 0, 
   opacity: 0,
   margin: 0,
   padding: 0
}, 'slow', function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: This one works better! I changed to marginTop/Bottom and paddingTop/Bottom to make it look nicer.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to do this with the `slideUp` and `fadeOut` methods themselves like so:

```js
$('#mydiv').slideUp(300, function(){
    console.log('Done!');
}).fadeOut({
    duration: 300,
    queue: false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and fixed it like this.

```
$('#mydiv').animate({
            height: 0,
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            complete: function(){$('#mydiv').css('display', 'none');}
        });
$('#mydiv').animate({
            opacity: 0,
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            queue: false
        });
```

the queue property tells it whether to queue the animation or just play it right away

Answer (score 2):

Throwing one more refinement in there based on @CodeKoalas. It accounts for vertical margin and padding but not horizontal.

```
$('.selector').animate({
    opacity: 0,
    height: 0,
    marginTop: 0,
    marginBottom: 0,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0
}, 'slow', function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```