# Fade out and slide up at the same time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I have the following script which works well:

```
$(that).parents(".portlet").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(that).parents(".portlet").remove();
});
```

It just fades out the element, then removes it totally from the screen.

I want to slightly improve the effect by sliding it up while it is fading out.  How would I do that?

Just to clarify, I don't want it to fade out THEN slide up, or slide up THEN fade out, I would like it to fade out, AND at the same time while it is fading out, I would like it to slide up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fadeOut() and slideUp() at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387515/fadeout-and-slideup-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$(that)
    .parents(".portlet")
    .animate({height: 0, opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

Comment: Dang, I'm too slow doing a jsfiddle :( ... Well, [here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Chouchen/p5AuB/)

Answer (score 4):

what about:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0,
    height: '0'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

will go to opacque 0 and height 0.

Learn more here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you can manipulate many properties at once - see [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3vXah/)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid jumping-effect do not forget about the padding & margin. The jQuery-Team does not use property 0. Instead they are using the values 'hide' & 'show'. e.g.

```
    $('#elementId').animate({
            opacity: 'hide',      // animate slideUp
            margin: 'hide',
            padding: 'hide',
            height: 'hide'        // animate fadeOut
        }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
            $(this).remove(); 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .animate function of jquery

you can set as many animations as you want.

pass opacity as the parameter & also slideUp as the parameter

api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$(that).parents(".portlet").animate({
    opacity: 0,
    height: 0
}, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
    $(that).parents(".portlet").remove();
});
```