# Fading effect on scroll with current script possible?

Tags: jquery, scroll, header, fade, sticky

I am using a very simply script for a sticky header. But when scrolling up i want it to fade. Is that possible with the current script i am using?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 500 && !$('header').hasClass('open') ) {
      $('header').addClass('open');
      $('header').slideDown();
    } else if ( $(this).scrollTop() <= 500 ) {
      $('header').removeClass('open');
      $('header').slideUp();
    }
});
```

[demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyx14te0/)

Comment: use     $('header').fadeOut();

Answer (score 0):

Use    `$('header').fadeOut('slow');`

https://jsfiddle.net/kyx14te0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use fadeout:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 500 && !$('header').hasClass('open') ) {
    $('header').addClass('open');
    $('header').slideDown();
  } else if ( $(this).scrollTop() <= 500 ) {
   $('header').removeClass('open');
   $('header').fadeOut();
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but i want to keep the slideUp effect. While slideUp it has to fade at the same time if possible.

Comment: Just go thriugh this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387515/fadeout-and-slideup-at-the-same-time