# JQuery: How do I trigger two animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if I could fadeout as well as slide the flash notification but that only one that works is the fadeOut. What can I do?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#flash_wrapper').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                      })
                }, 4500);
            });

      </script>
```

I want to be able to use `slideUp` and `FadeOut` at the same time. How do I do that? I still dont  know how to get these to work

Comment: possible duplicate of [fadeOut() and slideUp() at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387515/fadeout-and-slideup-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate CSS properties:

```
$('#flash_wrapper').animate({
        height: 0, // like slideUp
        opacity: 0 // like fadeOut
    },
    4500, // speed
    function () { // called when animation is complete
        $(this).remove();
    });
```