# Slide down transition effect for <div>

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

My requirement is to slide up & down `project_about` section on my [website](http://www.abitargroup.com/site/) where slide up is working fine but slide down on hiding just disappears on clicking the hide (X button). I want a transition effect in which it will slide down & hide with same transition as it does when sliding up and then take us to project section back.

Below is the code I have for sliding effect.

```
$(function() {

   $('#project_link').click(function(){
      $("#project").slideToggle(1000);
      $('#project_about').show();       

   });

   $('#close_link').click(function(){
      $("#project_about").slideUp(1000);
      $('#project').show(); 
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fadeOut() and slideUp() at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387515/fadeout-and-slideup-at-the-same-time)

Comment: not same time. As in you can see we click on ABOUT A PROJECT and it slides up that's perfect now clicking on CLOSE x should make it slide down in same transition style showing the Project page area.