# How to apply slide to elements moving up or down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to apply a `.slideUp()` or similar to the elements that are left after the elements that have faded out disapper. And apply `slideDown()` when they are pushed down by element reappearing. The point is I want the elements to move nice and easy. Thanks for all the help!!  Snippet below might explain better:

```js
var myJson = [];
    //Accordion-----------------------------------------------
    $(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
    $(".accordion").click(function () {
        $(".accordion-desc").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
        $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
    });


    $(".accordion").click(function () {
        $(".accordion").not(this).find(".rotate").removeClass("down");
        $(this).find(".rotate").toggleClass("down");
    });
    //-----------------------------------------------------------

    //SearchFilter
    $("#searcheBar").on("keyup", function () {
        var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".accordion #title").each(function () {
            var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if (s.indexOf(g) !== -1) {
                $(this).parent().parent().fadeIn();
            }
            else {
                $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: #2cc185;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2em 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
    background-color: #2cc185;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #239768;
    color: #fff;
}

button:focus {
    background-color: #239768;
    color: #fff;
}

.accordion {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #74777b;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/*Rotation-------------------------------------*/
.accordion .fa {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
.rotate {
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

    .rotate.down {
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
/*------------------------------------------*/
.link {

    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.accordion h4 {
    position: relative;
     /* top: 0.8em; */
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
}

.accordion a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #74777b;
    padding: 1em 1em 2.5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2cc185;
    background-color: #e7ecea;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion-desc {
    background-color: #f1f4f3;
    color: #74777b;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 20px 15px;
}
@media (min-width:480px) {

    .container { max-width: 80%; }
}
@media (min-width:768px) {

    .container { max-width: 1000px; }
}
.accordion-desc p {
    word-break: break-all;
}

.accordion .status {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 20%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.heading {
    margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.heading h2 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.heading .searcheBar {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.checkboxInput {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right: 40%;
}
.semi {
    min-height: 50px;   

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<b>Type 1, 2 or 3 in the text box</b>

    <div class="heading">
        <input class="searcheBar form-control" id="searcheBar" type="text" />
    </div>
 
                <div class="accordion">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h4 id="title">1</h4>
                        <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-desc">
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
                    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
                    <p>
                        @item.Description
                    <p>
                        <div class="link">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                        <div class="accordion">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h4 id="title">2</h4>
                        <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-desc">
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
                    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
                    <p>
                        @item.Description
                    <p>
                        <div class="link">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                        <div class="accordion">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h4 id="title">3</h4>
                        <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-desc">
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
                    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
                    <p>
                        @item.Description
                    <p>
                        <div class="link">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
 

    <div>

    </div><!-- end of container -->

</div><!-- end of accordion-container -->
```

Comment: Possible solution here: [fadeOut() and slideUp() at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387515/fadeout-and-slideup-at-the-same-time) Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/r363gyvh/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed a couple things in your code.

1. An `id` *must be unique*. So I used a `class` on titles.
2. It's a good idea to `.trim()` search inputs.
3. Then, on keyup, I close all accordions description before opening a matching one.
4. Also, I used a `:contains()` selector instead of an each loop.
5. And finally, I adjusted the effect timings to `10` milliseconds, intead of `fast`, which is `200` milliseconds, for the closing accordions.

Have a look at the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myJson = [];
  //Accordion-----------------------------------------------
  $(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
  $(".accordion").click(function () {
    $(".accordion-desc").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
  });


  $(".accordion").click(function () {
    $(".accordion").not(this).find(".rotate").removeClass("down");
    $(this).find(".rotate").toggleClass("down");
  });
  //-----------------------------------------------------------

  //SearchFilter
  $("#searcheBar").on("keyup", function () {

    // Close all accordions.
    $(".accordion").fadeIn(400);
    $(".accordion-desc").slideUp(10);


    // If g isn't empty
    var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase().trim();
    if(g!=""){
      $(".title:contains("+g+")").each(function () {
        $(this).closest(".accordion").next(".accordion-desc").slideDown(400);
        $(".accordion").not($(this).closest(".accordion")).fadeOut(10);
        $(this).closest(".accordion").fadeIn(400);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #2cc185;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2em 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  background-color: #2cc185;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #239768;
  color: #fff;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #239768;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #74777b;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/*Rotation-------------------------------------*/
.accordion .fa {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
/*------------------------------------------*/
.link {

  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.accordion h4 {
  position: relative;
  /* top: 0.8em; */
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
}

.accordion a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: #74777b;
  padding: 1em 1em 2.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2cc185;
  background-color: #e7ecea;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion-desc {
  background-color: #f1f4f3;
  color: #74777b;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px 15px;
}
@media (min-width:480px) {

  .container { max-width: 80%; }
}
@media (min-width:768px) {

  .container { max-width: 1000px; }
}
.accordion-desc p {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.accordion .status {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 20%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.heading {
  margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.heading h2 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin:auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.heading .searcheBar {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
.checkboxInput {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  right: 40%;
}
.semi {
  min-height: 50px;   

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <b>Type 1, 2 or 3 in the text box</b>

  <div class="heading">
    <input class="searcheBar form-control" id="searcheBar" type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#">
      <h4 class="title">1</h4>
      <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-desc">
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
    <h4>Kay Wiberg-1</h4>
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
    <p>
      @item.Description
    <p>
    <div class="link">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#">
      <h4 class="title">2</h4>
      <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-desc">
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
    <h4>Kay Wiberg-2</h4>
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
    <p>
      @item.Description
    <p>
    <div class="link">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#">
      <h4 class="title">3</h4>
      <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-desc">
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
    <h4>Kay Wiberg-3</h4>
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
    <p>
      @item.Description
    <p>
    <div class="link">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div>

  </div><!-- end of container -->

</div><!-- end of accordion-container -->
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Thanks for taking your time with my code. I will try I out as soon as I can.

Comment: Tried your code. Thanks for your help! it works.Marking your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var myJson = [];
    //Accordion-----------------------------------------------
    $(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
    $(".accordion").click(function () {
        $(".accordion-desc").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
        $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
    });


    $(".accordion").click(function () {
      //$(".accordion").not(this).find(".rotate").removeClass("down");
       // $(this).find(".rotate").toggleClass("down");
    });
    //-----------------------------------------------------------

    //SearchFilter
    $("#searcheBar").on("keyup", function () {
         $(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
        var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".accordion #title").each(function() {
           if( g && $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(g)>-1) {
             $(this).closest('.accordion').click();
           }
        });
        return;
       
    });
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: #2cc185;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2em 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
    background-color: #2cc185;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #239768;
    color: #fff;
}

button:focus {
    background-color: #239768;
    color: #fff;
}

.accordion {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #74777b;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/*Rotation-------------------------------------*/
.accordion .fa {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
.rotate {
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

    .rotate.down {
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
/*------------------------------------------*/
.link {

    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.accordion h4 {
    position: relative;
     /* top: 0.8em; */
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
}

.accordion a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #74777b;
    padding: 1em 1em 2.5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2cc185;
    background-color: #e7ecea;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion-desc {
    background-color: #f1f4f3;
    color: #74777b;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 20px 15px;
}
@media (min-width:480px) {

    .container { max-width: 80%; }
}
@media (min-width:768px) {

    .container { max-width: 1000px; }
}
.accordion-desc p {
    word-break: break-all;
}

.accordion .status {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 20%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.heading {
    margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.heading h2 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.heading .searcheBar {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.checkboxInput {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right: 40%;
}
.semi {
    min-height: 50px;   

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<b>Type 1, 2 or 3 in the text box</b>

    <div class="heading">
        <input class="searcheBar form-control" id="searcheBar" type="text" />
    </div>
 
                <div class="accordion">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h4 id="title">1</h4>
                        <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-desc">
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
                    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
                    <p>
                        @item.Description
                    <p>
                        <div class="link">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                        <div class="accordion">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h4 id="title">2</h4>
                        <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-desc">
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
                    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
                    <p>
                        @item.Description
                    <p>
                        <div class="link">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                        <div class="accordion">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h4 id="title">3</h4>
                        <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-desc">
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
                    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
                    <p>
                        @item.Description
                    <p>
                        <div class="link">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
 

    <div>

    </div><!-- end of container -->

</div><!-- end of accordion-container -->
```

Comment: I'll try your code as soon as I can.