# jQuery slideDown() and slideUp() effect issue

Tags: jquery

Basically, I use the `$.get()` function to retrieve data from the website. When data is received, it should slide up existing content and slide down new content.

Here is my code:

```
$.get(url, so, function (data) {
    if (data.length>0)
    {
        $("#center_content_box").slideToggle(2000).empty().html(data).slideToggle(2000);
    }
});
```

The problem is that if the new content is displayed then the effect happens. I want an effect similar to `http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/BusinessCard/` when links are clicked. The contents slideup fade and slidedown and then fade again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use animation completion handler to set your data to div.

```
$.get(url, so, function (data) {
            if (data.length>0)
                {
                $("#center_content_box").slideToggle(2000,function(){
                     $("#center_content_box").empty().html(data).slideToggle(2000);
                });
}
});
```

Please visit [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mv5cb/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the animation completion handler to test when the animation is complete

```js
$("#item").slideDown('slow', function(){
                                   $("#item").html("Set content here after effect is done");
                             });
```

Shai.

Comment: ive done this and the slide effect seems to work.im confused on how to get the fade effect as shown in that link. $("#center_content_box").slideUp(2000,function () { $("#center_content_box").empty().html(data).slideDown(2000)});

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734554/jquery-fadeout-then-slideup