# jQuery effect - What is the name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There use to be a jQuery effect that when you initlized it.. the DIV/CLASS would slide up and fade away at the same time. I know it's not puff... but it was something. I remember becuase I found out about it after doing slide/fade when I was like.. oh I could have done this instead.

But I can't find it on jQuery UI website anymore... help?

I tried searching Google and especially jQuery API:  http://api.jquery.com

Comment: `slideUp()` maybe? http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: `$(this).animate({height: 'hide', opacity: 'hide'});`

Comment: second example http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These links might help you 
slideUp and fadeOut is what you need

[jQuery: FadeOut then SlideUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734554/jquery-fadeout-then-slideup)

more information with examples

1 . http://www.elated.com/articles/super-easy-animated-effects-with-jquery/

2 . http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/forms/article.php/3896356/HTML-Forms-jQuery-  Basics----Effects.htm

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) together.

Comment: What does "sounds like animate" mean? Animate what?